# How to optimize this Mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Need guidance on Query optimizations. 
I have two tables userEvents and events

```
userEvents
id |  userName | eventID

events
id |  name
```

I need to find all the events name which has not eventID in userEvents

```
select id, name
from  events
where id NOT IN ( select eventid
                  from userEvents
                  inner join events on events.id = userEvents.eventid
                  group by userEvents.eventID
                )
```

I am able to get the result .I want to know how can I OPTIMIZE this query since there are large number of rows .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN userEvents AS v ON e.id = v.eventid
WHERE e.id IS NULL;
```

**Or:** remove the `INNER JOIN` inside the subquery, you didn't need it:

```
select id, name 
from  events 
where id NOT IN (select eventid 
                 from userEvents 
                 where eventid IS NOT NULL)
```

**Note that:** the predicate `IN` is not safe with the `NULL` values coming from the `eventid` column, thats why I added `eventid IS NOT NULL` to the subquery. `LEFT JOIN` will be safer in this case.

Comment: where condition should be e.eventID is null